# How to use new Result type introduced in swift 5 URLSession?

Tags: urlsession, swift5

Swift 5 introduces new Result type to handle the result of an asynchronous function. I want to know the way to use this new result type for URLSession.

> I have this following code.

```
func getCategorByAPI()
    {
        //Base Url is from an static variable
        let url = URL(string: URLManager.aPIBaseURL+"category")!
        var request  = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                //print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                print(json)
            }catch
            {
                print(error)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

How can i rewrite this function using swift 5 Result type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to create an `enum` that specifies the possible cases in your result (e.g. success or failure). Then you add a completion to your `getCategorByAPI()` method that is of type `Result<Data, Error>`. From there, inside url session, you will call your completion handler passing in either the `data` on `.success` or the `error` on `.failure`.

You can also do cool things like override Result's `get()` method and extend `Result` to decode your data :D

Check it out:

```
enum Result<Success, Error: Swift.Error> {
    case success(Success)
    case failure(Error)
}

// override the Result.get() method
extension Result {
    func get() throws -> Success {
        switch self {
        case .success(let value):
            return value
        case .failure(let error):
            throw error
        }
    }
}

// use generics - this is where you can decode your data
extension Result where Success == Data {
    func decoded<T: Decodable>(using decoder: JSONDecoder = .init()) throws -> T {
        let data = try get()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
}


func getCategorByAPI(completion: (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void)
{
    // You might want to stick this into another method
    let url = URL(string: URLManager.aPIBaseURL+"category")!
    var request  = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        if !(200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) && !(httpResponse.statusCode == 304) {
            let httpError = // ... convert httpResponse.statusCode into a more readable error
                completion(.failure(httpError))
        }

        if let data = data {
            completion(.success(data))
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

I haven't tested the above but have something like this implemented in a current project. Here are some articles I read to learn about how to implement:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/161/how-to-use-result-in-swift
https://medium.com/@pavlepesic/how-to-use-swift-5-result-with-codable-protocol-824c9a951af9

Comment: Thanks @christinam , that was great help indeed, both code and links were helpful to me.  in above code there need to add a line of code before checking status code. 'let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse'

Answer (score 5):

I have written an extension on URLSession which abstracts out the boilerplate code of error handling and decoding.

```
extension URLSession {

    /// A type safe URL loader that calls completion handler with Result type
    func jsonDecodableTask<T: Decodable>(with url: URLRequest, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        self.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(error!))
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(URLError.noData))
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoded = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(decoded))
            } catch  {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }

    func jsonDecodableTask<T: Decodable>(with url: URL, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
       self.jsonDecodableTask(with: URLRequest(url: url), decoder: decoder, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

---

## Usage

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

let url = URL(string: "https://abcd.com")!

URLSession.shared.jsonDecodableTask(with: url) { (result: Result<Person, Error>) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let person):
        print("Person \(person.name)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

You can also pass your own `JSONDecoder` like this

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
URLSession.shared.jsonDecodableTask(with: urlRequest, decoder: decoder) { (result: Result<Person, Error>) in
    // Same as above
}.resume()
```

Comment: Could you please share, how did you call this function. Thanks