# Try Catch Never Executes for JSONDecoder in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to safely decode a JSON response from an API. I get the response fine, but it fails while decoding. But what I'm having trouble with, is instead of executing any of the code in the catch blocks, it fails out of the method altogether and prints the error message to the console. I realize I also need to figure out how to  return a .failure instead of just printing to console, but right now I just want to figure out why try/catch isn't doing anything at all. Can anyone tell me why these catches are never executing? Thanks!

```
func forcePlaidResync(
        userId: String,
        bearerToken: String,
        completion: @escaping (Result<BaseResponse, Error>) -> Void) {
            guard let url = URL(string: "\(baseUrl)/resync/\(userId)") else {
                return
            }
            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue( "Bearer \(bearerToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, _, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    completion(.failure(error!))
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let response = try decoder.decode(BaseResponse.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(response))
                } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
                    print("test1")
                } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
                    print("\test2")
                } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
                    print("test3")
                } catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let type, let context) {
                    print("test4")
                } catch {
                    print("Something went wrong")
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: I think this will be 
[helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55876601/6261095)

Comment: Just do `catch { print(error) }` instead of all that fancy stuff to see what actually goes wrong with the decoding

Comment: I did have that at first, but it never executes. I put a break point within the catch but it never gets hit.

Comment: Then how far does it go, is the closure even called? And please use @<username> when responding to a comment so that we get notified.